# ring-json vs. cheshire for Clojure web development

Tags: json, web, clojure, ring

I've looked online and have seen either or both of these used on every example of a clojure web app. I am writing an app and would like to use json, but I'm not sure which one to choose or if they are the same thing. What is the difference? Should I use both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are different things. Cheshire is a json encoding/decoding library for clojure.Ring-json is a middleware for Ring, it uses Cheshire.

So if you want to build a json web application, just use ring-json, follow  the example in its gitthub page, it's quite simple.